# How to transform array of core data managed objects into an "identifiable" list, in swift? (Xcode 11, Beta 5)

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode11, ios13

How would one transfer an array of managed objects retrieved from Core Data using Swift/IOS via a "fetchRequest", to an array that is "identifiable"?

Example - How to make the "tasks" array "identifiable"

```
let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<Todo> = Todo.fetchRequest()
let tasks = try context?.fetch(fetchRequest)
```

Background:

- In SwiftUI using a "List" the array of data you pass to the List needs to be "identifiable".
- I also note the identified(by: .self) seems to be deprecated.
- Using (Xcode 11, Beta 5)
- Currently using xcode's automatic creation of managed objects for the core data entities, so would be nice to stick with this approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use replacement `ForEach(Data, id: \.idAttribute)`

The feature `identified(by: .self)` was replaced with the new syntax:

```
ForEach(filteredGrapes, id: \.id) { grape in
    GrapeCell(grape: grape)
}
```

### Coredata example:

Using a file named `ItemStore.xcdatamodeld` with an entity `ItemDAO` defined with `Generation=Class Definition` enabled and having a String-attribute named `title`.

Note: One has to `Product/Clear Build Folder` and afterwards restart Xcode to make Xcode11Beta5 find the proper key path, which seems to be a bug in Xcode11Beta5.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

class MyItemStore {
    public static func defaultItems() -> [ItemDAO]{
        let store = NSPersistentContainer(name: "ItemStore")
        store.loadPersistentStores { (desc, err) in
            if let err = err {
                fatalError("core data error: \(err)")
            }
        }
        let context = store.viewContext
        let item = ItemDAO(context: context)
        item.title = "hello you"
        try! context.save()
        return [
            item,
            item,
        ]
    }
}

struct CoreDataView: View {
    let items: [ItemDAO] = MyItemStore.defaultItems()

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach(items, id: \.title) { (item: ItemDAO) in
                Text(item.title ?? "no title")
            }
            Text("hi")
        }
    }
}
```

## Adding Identifiable via Extension

```
extension Todo: Identifiable {
    public var id: String {
        //return self.objectID.uriRepresentation().absoluteString
        return self.title!
    }
}
```

## Maintaining CoreData models manually to add `Identifiable`

There you can add `Identifiable` as usual, which is not necessary though since an extension can add Identifiable too.

Comment: I've just tried this concept with a core data entity which just has one attribute "title", a string, so I have "id: \.title", however I then get a build error:  "type '_' has no member 'title'".   (line in question: "ForEach(todoStore.getTodoItems(), id: \.title) { item in")

Comment: @Greg Added an example. You may have to restart Xcode for it to find the key path, which sounds like a bug.

Comment: did just try this but it didn't help - almost as if it can't pick up the "title" attribute from the automatically generated (that I can't in my xcode project) Todo managed object created from my core data model...(?)

Comment: got it - I changed to manually creating the managed subclasses, and saw here that xcode was making the "title" attribute optional, although in the coredata designer it wasn't... it's now picking up the "title" attribute ok

Comment: Good that it works now. I think it's more akin to an Xcode bug, since I have to Clear the build folder and afterwards restart Xcode for it to pick up the key path properly. This way Class-Definition generation works for me too.